# Block with articles from the same author

Tags: 7, views

My websites publishes articles by third party authors. Articles are inserted by an admin. Every article has its author.
The authors' info are in a content type called Bio, which has these fields: title (full name of the author), picture, body, links to social networks. The path to each author's bio is /author/.
In each author page, I want to show all the articles this author has already published on my website. So I made a view that should display a block in each of those pages.

The problem with the view is that it works in preview, when I manually enter the name of the author, but it isn't working when in the page as a block. It doesn't retrieve the  from the url, I guess.

Here's some screenshots of my view:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Content Titolo` use `Contenuto: Identificativo uid dell'autore`

and use the following settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't work since it would retrieve the user that creates the content, which is always the admin in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a new field to the Bio content type that acts as a "primary key" between the Article and the Bio content type. I also use this field to create the path of the author's bio, so that I can get that value through contextual filter (Raw value from URL).